# How to load a local Test.html file inside a iframe in the Blazor server template

Tags: html, iframe, blazor-server-side, local-files

I cant figure out how to load a local file into my Blazor Server template.
I want to load the Test.html file inside a iframe on the Index.razor page of the template.
The Test.html file is saved inside the same folder than the Index.razor file. But it wouldnt show? How to do it right?

```html
@page "/"

<h1>Main Blazor</h1>

<iframe src="Test.html" width="600" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get it to work by doing this:

Dont put the test.html inside the Page-Folder from Blazor instead put it in the
wwwroot folder (to be more oderly I created a folder there "MyHtmlPages")
And moved the test file there.

And this is the html from my blazor index.razor page that calls/shows the file successfully:

```html
<iframe src="/MyHtmPages/Test.html" width="600" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```