# I have a Blazor server side app. How can I display a text file in my razor page directly in an iframe?

Tags: c#, file, blazor-server-side, streamreader

I have a Blazor server side app. Currently I am reading the file line by line and adding each line to a list. Then I am displaying each list element (line) in a table row by row in my razor file.

Is there a possiblity to display the file content directly in my razor file (for example iframe)? My text file is on the server where my app is running.

My current cs file

```
public void read_file_content() 
{
var lines = File.ReadLines(TagService.PLC_alarm_text_path,Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254"));                   
                
   foreach (var line in lines)
   {
      TagService.PLC_alarm_text_definition.Add(line);
   }
}
```

My current razor file

```
    <table>
        @for (int f = 0; f < TagService.PLC_alarm_text_definition.Count; f++)
        {
          <tr>
              <td>@TagService.PLC_alarm_text_definition[f]</td>                    
          </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166381/how-to-load-a-local-test-html-file-inside-a-iframe-in-the-blazor-server-template

Comment: @jeb My file is somewhere under D:/ drive of my server where the app is running. I cannot move it to the wwwroot folder. I have tried with file:///D:/test/log.txt   but there is nothing shown in the iframe. Can it be related with browser? (firefox)

Comment: You can add a controller to download the file if that is what you are looking for. I am not sure if I understand the question correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407886/reading-server-side-files-using-blazor